# ML.NET Transform data without fitting

Tags: c#, machine-learning, data-science, ml.net

### Intro

Hi, I want to do some data preparation actions, and the put the `DataView` to another method, or use it in multiple places.

So, I creating an `IEstimator<ITransformer>` object to hold the pipeline, for example:

```
var textEstimator = mlContext.Transforms.Text.NormalizeText("Description")
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.TokenizeIntoWords("Description"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.RemoveDefaultStopWords("Description"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Description"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.ProduceNgrams("Description"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeLpNorm("Description"));
```

(Copied from [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/prepare-data-ml-net#work-with-text-data))

But now, I want to get the `DataView`, and remember, this is **not** learning pipeline yet.

---

### The question

So why I have to `Fit` the pipeline before `Tranform`?

```cs
// Fit data to estimator
// Fitting generates a transformer that applies the operations of defined by estimator
ITransformer textTransformer = textEstimator.Fit(data);

// Transform data
IDataView transformedData = textTransformer.Transform(data);
```

Comment: [Cross-reference to docs issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/13332)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Fit builds a chain of transformers from a chain of the estimators you setup using the convenience methods on the MLContext. Transformers do the actual work of transforming your data.

You are correct that most of your Estimators do little work apart from returning their corresponding Transformer but when at some point turning this into a learning pipeline the similar structure will benefit you greatly.